# ((QuickFix.FIXT11.Logon)message).Password threw an exception like QuickFix.FieldNotFoundException

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I need to implement an acceptor using QuickFix/n. The way to create and run an acceptor is as follows:

```cs
public FixAcceptorManager(FixOptions options,ILogFactory logFactory,IApplication acceptor,SessionSettings sessionSettings)
{
    _options = options;
    _acceptor = acceptor;
    _logFactory = logFactory;
    _settings = sessionSettings;
    _soketAcceptor = CreateSocketAcceptor();
    _server = new HttpServer(_options.Url, _settings);
    _isRunning = false;
}

private ThreadedSocketAcceptor CreateAcceptor()
{
    var storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(_settings);
    var threadSocketAcceptor = new ThreadedSocketAcceptor(_acceptor, storeFactory, _settings, _logFactory);

    return threadSocketAcceptor;
}

public void StartAcceptor()
{
    if (_soketAcceptor is not null && !_isRunning)
    {
        _soketAcceptor.Start();
        _server.Start();
        _isRunning = true;
    }
}
```

I create sessions dynamically as follows:

```cs
public void AddSession(string targetCompId, string password)
{
    var dictionarySettings = new Dictionary();

    dictionarySettings.SetString("Password", password);

    var sessionId = new SessionID("FIXT.1.1", "TEST", targetCompId);

    _soketAcceptor.AddSession(sessionId, dictionarySettings);
}
```

Everything starts, sessions are added. Active sessions are displayed on the panel. I also created a simple initiator for the test:

```cs
SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(file);

MyClientApp application = new MyClientApp();
IMessageStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
ILogFactory logFactory = new ScreenLogFactory(settings);
SocketInitiator initiator = new SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory);

application.MyInitiator = initiator;

initiator.Start();
Console.ReadLine();
initiator.Stop();
```

The initiator connects to the acceptor, Logon is successful.

The acceptor has the following configuration:

```
[DEFAULT]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
HeartBtInt=20
AppDataDictionary=FIXRTv1.xml
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
#EncryptMethod = 6
FileLogPath=log
SocketAcceptPort=9823 
ConnectionType=acceptor
UseDataDictionary=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
#ValidateUserDefinedFields = N
SenderCompID=MyAcceptor
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:00
FileStorePath=store
#AllowUnknownMsgFields = Y
```

And the initiator configuration:

```
[DEFAULT]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=20
AppDataDictionary=FIXRTv1.xml
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
UseDataDictionary=Y

ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
ValidateUserDefinedFields = N
EncryptMethod = 6

[SESSION]
SenderCompID=MyInitiator
TargetCompID=MyAcceptor
Password=testtest
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1 
SocketConnectPort=9823

StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:00
```

I pass a Password to the acceptor to set up a new session. This Password is different from the one defined in the initiator configuration.

Then I start the initiator. And it connects with its own password. Although the password the acceptor expects from this initiator is different. Moreover, in the FromAdmin method of the acceptor I can't see the Password field in any way. I also tried to use Crack:

```
public void FromAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID)
{
    Crack(message, sessionID);
}

public void OnMessage(QuickFix.FIXT11.Logon logon, SessionID s)
{
    try
    {
        var p = logon.GetString(554); // Password field in FIXT11.xml tag = 554
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Attempting to remove Password from the message results in an exception. Also in Debug mode in VisualStudio, when hovering over a message for the Password field, I see the following message:

"((QuickFix.FIXT11.Logon)message).Password" threw an exception like "QuickFix.FieldNotFoundException"

The FIXRTv1.xml and FIXT11.xml files are the same. The Logon message section looks like this:

```xml
<message msgcat='admin' msgtype='A' name='Logon'>
  <field name='EncryptMethod' required='Y'/>
  <field name='HeartBtInt' required='Y'/>
  <field name='RawDataLength' required='N'/>
  <field name='RawData' required='N'/>
  <field name='ResetSeqNumFlag' required='N'/>
  <field name='NextExpectedMsgSeqNum' required='N'/>
  <field name='MaxMessageSize' required='N'/>
  <field name='TestMessageIndicator' required='N'/>
  <field name='Username' required='N'/>
  <field name='Password' required='N'/>
  <field name='NewPassword' required='N' />
  <field name='DefaultApplVerID' required='N'/>
  <component name='MsgTypeGrp' required='N'/>
</message>
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? I need to extract the Password field in the acceptor, validate and reject the initiator's Logon if the passwords do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot going on in this question, so I'll try to break it up:

**"Password" is not a QF/n config setting**

[This page](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html) shows the list of supported settings.  "Password" isn't one of them.  Your app is ignoring it.

Likewise, your `dictionarySettings.SetString("Password", password);` line is also doing nothing.

**Let's focus on the initiator-- do you see a password in its outbound Logon message?**

And by "log", I mean the raw message transmissions log.  I see you are using a ScreenLogFactory; I suggest you switch over to a FileLogFactory.  After you run the initiator, look in the message log and find the 35=A outbound logon message.  Does you see a password 554=xxx field?

I suspect you aren't seeing it, because you aren't actually setting it (as described above).

Try doing it via the ToAdmin callback instead:

```
public void ToAdmin(Message msg, SessionID sessionID) {
    if (msg.Header.GetString(Tags.MsgType) == "A") {
        msg.SetField(new Password("mypassword");
    }
}
```

*Now* you should see, in your logs, that the Initiator is sending a password.

**One last bit: You should check for the password's presence before reading it**

Like this:

```
if (login.IsSetField(554)) {
    var p = logon.GetString(554); 
}
```

Give all of that a try, and see how it goes.

Comment: thanks so much! It really works. Can you please tell me if it is possible to encrypt the password at the session level by the initiator and decrypt it at the acceptor? Maybe there are some additional FIX fields that can also be set in the message? So that it doesn't show up password in the logs.

Comment: FIX provides fields 1400-1404 for an encrypted password, but does not specify any concrete way to use them.  If you are the acceptor party, then you make the rules; any initiator that wants to connect to you has to obey your rules.